# python3 parsing and wikipedia page

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, html-parsing, wikipedia

So I need to get the first 10 links from the 'Computer Science' wikipedia page. And then I need to get 10 links for every that link from CS page. So I will have 10*10 = 100 links in the end.

Untill now I wrote this code:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science').read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")


for link in soup.find_all('a', limit=10):
    rez=link.get('href')
    for i in rez.find_all('a', limit=10):
        print(i)
```

And when I run it I'm getting this error:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

---

Thanks, this helps a lot. Next i need to get 10 links from every returned link, i.e. 10 links from Programming_language_theory, Computational_complexity_theory.. etc. I tried to do this part like this:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True, limit=10):
        print(link['href'])
        for link2 in link['href'].find_all('a', href=True, title=True, limit=10):
            print(link2['href'])
```

But I'm getting an error: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue I see is that the first three items returned when I run this snippet:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', limit=10):
    rez=link.get('href')
    print(rez)
```

are:

`None`
`#mw-head`
`#p-search`

Which is why when you invoke `rez.find_all()` python is telling you `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`.

**Edit#2:**
A possible solution to eliminate the `None` return and find the article's links and sub-links is:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True, limit=10):
        print(link['href'])
        sub_html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org' + link['href'])
        sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_html, "lxml")
        for sub_link in sub_soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True, limit=10):
            print(sub_link['href'])
```

The reason for your new issue is that you needed to create a new soup object for the new link, and `link['href']` is only a string.

Comment: I want the first 10 links, the content of them isn't important. So because of that I wrote find_all('a'), isn't that correct?

Comment: Edited for your revised question